# Estimate minimum mass A of unstable nuclei for $\alpha$ decay

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation

I want to estimate a minimum mass $A$ from which nuclei can be unstable for $\alpha$ decay using the liquid drop model.

I started by writing the reaction's Q value for the usual $\alpha$ decay, in terms of the binding energy of each component.

$$
(Z,A) \longrightarrow (Z-2, A-4) + \alpha \\
Q = -B(Z,A) + B(Z-2,A-4) + B(2,4)
$$

Then, considering that we need $Q \geq 0$ for an $\alpha$ decay to be possible, I used the semi-empirical mass formula to write the equation above in terms of the binding energy

$$
B(2,4) = -4a_v - a_s\left[A^{2/3} - (A-4)^{2/3} \right] - a_c\left[\frac
{Z^2}{A^{1/3}} -  \frac
{(Z-2)^2}{(A-4)^{1/3}}\right] + a_A\left[\frac
{(A-2Z)^2}{A} - \frac
{(A-2Z)^2}{A-4}\right],
$$
assuming odd $A$ to make things easier.

Using the binding energy for an $\alpha$ particle as $28.3\,\text{MeV}$, I tried testing $Z = 80$ and making approximations for $A\gg 1$ to find an analytic solution for this equation, isolating A. Unfortunately, the value I could find were far away from a reasonable value for A (around 140).

Williams' Nuclear and Particle Physics book has a similar calculation (p. 74), but it uses the experimental data in one of its graphs. I wanted to find an approximate analytical solution.

My questions are:

- Can I really choose the pairing term to be zero or is that an oversimplification?
- Is even possible to find an analytical solution or am I missing something?